# How can we simplify this integral? $\int{x\frac{f(x)}{\int f(x) dx} dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

In a machine learning lecture, we encountered the following integral that we needed to solve to calculate the mean of some random variable $x$:

\begin{equation*}
  \int{x\frac{f(x)}{\int f(x) dx} dx}
\end{equation*}

Without really explaining, the professor just simplified it to this:

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\int x f(x) dx}{\int f(x) dx}
\end{equation*}

I'm not sure how that works. Since the integration is without limits, then the result is a function not a constant, right? It can't be factored out as if it were a constant. Am I missing something? Does integrating on the same variable twice have any special properties that are relevant here?

I'm sorry if the question is lacking in details, if there's anything I can edit to make it clearer, please let me know.

Edit: The problem is solved. The simplification is because the denominator is a definite integral and I didn't understand that at first. Since the result of a definite is just a constant, it can be factored outside the integral.

Comment: This depends on what the bounds of the integral are.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that is the only way that it could make sense. The professor doesn't say if the integral in the denominator has bounds, but otherwise, it just seems unsolvable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should read$$\int x\frac{f(x)}{\int_a^bf(y)dy}dx=\frac{\int xf(x)dx}{\int_a^bf(y)dy},$$where the $x$-integral may or may not be definite (though in this context it would be).

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe it is meant to read something like:
$$\int_a^bx\frac{f(x)}{\int_a^bf(x)dx}dx$$
as then the bottom integral is a constant and you can bring it outside:
$$\frac{1}{\int_a^bf(x)dx}\int_a^bxf(x)dx=\frac{\int_a^bxf(x)dx}{\int_a^bf(x)dx}$$

---

Or maybe if it is:
$$\int x\frac{f(x)}{\int f(x)dx}dx$$
then you can define:
$$F(x)=\int f(x)dx$$ so you get:
$$\int x\frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}dx=\int\frac{F^{-1}(u)}{u}du$$
I don't really understand the notation but its a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

call $Q= x f(x) $, then our integral is:

$$ \int \frac{Q}{\int f(x) dx} dx $$

Now integrating by parts:

$$ \frac{ \int Q dx}{\int f(x) dx} +\int \frac{\int Q dx}{ ( \int f(x) dx)^2} f(x) dx$$

For the above to be equal to, $ \frac{ \int x f(x) dx}{\int f(x) dx} i.e: \frac{\int Q dx}{\int f(x) dx}$,

$$ \int \frac{ \int Q dx}{ (\int f(x) dx )^2} f(x) dx= 0$$

So, the equality you wrote is only true for functions $f(x)$ which satisfy above criteria.

Comment: Putting aside the OP's uncertainty, he did mention 'random variable.' Almost surely (haha - probability joke) the integrals are definite, and we are talking about some kind of mean, and the integral in the denominator is a 'scalar.' Namely, I would guess that this is not about 'solving a calculus problem.'

Comment: @peterag
Ah, I see. Sorry, I'm relatively clueless when it comes to probability theory.
If the integral has to be a definite integral, then the result is a constant that can just be factored out of the big integral. That already explains everything. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm , I think this still counts as an answer :P

Answer (score -1):

This is a typical abuse of notation.

Unless we have bounds on an integral, like $\int_a^b$, the integral $\int f(x)dx$ stands for a primitive function of $f$.
However, according to the argument of your professor he/she really means an integral with bounds.

Comment: Well, that is not true. In higher level mathematics, the notation in question is never for used for denoting an antiderivative, and on the other hand, it is quite common to denote integrals (definite ones) without bounds, specially in the context of measure theory or probability theory. In fact, using bounds is technically a bigger abuse of notation, because if $f$ is well-defined as a function, then that means its domain need not be specified, in which case, the bounds are literally redundant. The problem is that, when doing calculus, you never work with well-defined integrads.